# Index mapping request in ElasticSearch using NEST in C#

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I need to create an index with mapping using a json string provided from the input. I am trying to pass the json mapping string in a lowlevel client since my usecase has a long list of mappings which I can not do using a high-level client. However, it is creating a null mapping with the lowlevel client I am using. Below is a simple example of my mapping json string.

```
mappingString = {
"mappings" : {  
"exchangeid" : {
          "type" : "double"
        }
}
```

Below is the code snippet which I am using to create an index and then lowlevel request to create the mapping.

```
        CreateIndexResponse createIndexResponse = ElasticAccessor.Client.Indices.Create(IndexName, c => c
        .InitializeUsing(indexConfig));

        // Put mapping request
        StringResponse putMappingRequest = ElasticAccessor.Client.LowLevel.DoRequest<StringResponse>(HttpMethod.PUT, 
            "/" + IndexName + "/_mapping", 
            PostData.String(this.mappingString));
```

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The mapping string JSON format is [not correct for an Update Mapping API call](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.12/indices-put-mapping.html). It's *closer* to the format used when creating an index with a mapping, [but still not correct](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.12/indices-create-index.html#mappings).

To make a call with the low level client to create an index and mapping at the same time

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient();

var IndexName = "my-index";

var request = @"{
    ""mappings"": {
        ""properties"": {
            ""exchangeid"": { ""type"": ""double"" }
        }
    }
}";

var response = client.LowLevel.Indices.Create<StringResponse>(IndexName, request);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. The mapping thing works. However, I was wondering how can I attach IndexSettings such as NumberOfReplicas = 1, NumberOfShards = 2 etc. in this lowlevel client along with mappings. I used to do it in using a indexConfig in the high-level client as follows.                   
   CreateIndexResponse createIndexResponse = ElasticAccessor.Client.Indices.Create(IndexName, c => c
                .InitializeUsing(indexConfig));